# removing background of imported picture in Inscape

Tags: inkscape

I am new to inkscape and was hoping someone can give me a step by step to remove background in a picture.

Thanks

Comment: Inkscape is a vector graphics program. Removing the background of a piece of vector graphics is very likely possible by redefining which is opaque and making boolean operations. Removing a background from a photo needs mask drawing with the pen. In some cases tracing can generate the needed mask. By using a bitmap graphics program one can use several tools for masking and erasing areas in photos. You should show a couple of images which you want to process.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  What kind of picture is it? Can we see an example of what you are trying to acheive? Please [edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/124552/edit) to clarify. If it's a raster image, then Inkscape probably isn't the right kind of software for that task, unless you want a vector clipping path/mask.

Answer (score 2):

Inkscape is not the right tool for removing a background from a raster graphic (PNG, JPG, BMP, etc). Inkscape is for editing vector graphics, specifically SVG files.

If you are trying to remove a background from a raster graphic (which it sounds like you are), you can [use GIMP for that](https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-tutorial-quickie-separate.html). GIMP is free/open source like Inkscape.

*Note: If you are trying to remove a background from an SVG file, Inkscape can do that. Simply select and delete the background object, or change the document background color (File > Document Properties). The background might be grouped with another object or on another layer.*

Comment: You can use Ctl-Shift-G to ungroup objects in your search for the background object to delete.